# How to redirect webspages_

Tags: javascript, html, web

So basically I want to make it so when a user joins the index.html page they will automatically be transferred to the home.html page. I tried researching this but I didn't find anything that helped so please could someone help me.

Comment: You didn't find anywhere on the internet how to make a redirection in Javascript?

Comment: Resisting the temptation to lmgtfy this: [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) is settable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with meta-tag:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=yourUrl">
</head>
```

Or just javascript:

```
window.location.href=yourUrl
```

Comment: Thank you this helped alot! (Gonna tag you in the credits)